# Command line ffmpeg, to insert part of a mp3 audio to another file

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Want to copy from 3rd second of `b.mp3` till 2:05 seconds of `b.mp3` and append to the end of `a.mp3` (its 3:23 long).

Command:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -i b.mp3
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0.4-0ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 8 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'a.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:02:48.00, start: 0.011021, bitrate: 144 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 144 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18
Input #1, mp3, from 'b.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:01:33.02, start: 0.011995, bitrate: 117 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 117 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -i b.mp3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your inputs have the same channel layout and sampling rate you can use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) with the inpoint/outpoint directives. This has the advantage of avoiding re-encoding, so quality is preserved and the process will be fast.

Make `input.txt`:

```
file 'a.mp3'
file 'b.mp3'
inpoint 3
outpoint 122
```

Run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy -vn output.mp3
```

Alternatively, use the atrim, asepts, and concat filters, but filtering requires encoding and will be slower.